# Clone an internal repository from the GitHub Action of another internal repository without PAT?

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I have 2 repositories within a GitHub organization:

1. https://github.com/my-org/site
2. https://github.com/my-org/shared-pipelines

From the `site` repo, I use the enterprise feature of referencing another internal GitHub Action:

```yaml
# [...]
jobs:
  deploy:
    name: Deploy

    uses: 'my-org/shared-pipelines/.github/workflows/deploy.yml@main'
# [...]
```

I would like to check out the code of `my-org/shared-pipelines` from the `my-org/shared-pipelines/.github/workflows/deploy.yml` GitHub Action to get access to the files in the repo.

Is that possible without having to generate a Personal Access Token that gives access to all the same repos I have access to?

*Fine-grained personal access tokens* (currently in beta) don't let me chose an internal repo as scope, only the ones under my own account. Trying to check out using [actions/checkout@v3](https://github.com/actions/checkout) with or without `persist-credentials` results in a "Not found" error.

Comment: According to the [official documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/enabling-features-for-your-repository/managing-github-actions-settings-for-a-repository#allowing-access-to-components-in-a-private-repository), you shouldn't need a PAT to access a reusable workflow from a private repository in the same organization but just managing the access in the repository settings.

Comment: You're right. That's what makes the `uses` line above work. However, that setting only applies to the workflows and not the contents of the repository, as far as I can tell.